# using ES2015 with mocha, karma and headless chrome for testing

Tags: mocha.js, tdd, karma-runner, chai, google-chrome-headless

I have a problem with setting up a test environment for a single page application. I am able to run my tests with headless chrome via karma and mocha but I can´t write tests with ES6 Syntax.

My current start command is

```
karma start --browsers ChromeHeadless karma.config.js --single-run
```

my karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        files: ['test/**/*spec.js'],
        reporters: ['nyan'],
        port: 9876,  // karma web server port
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false, // Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        concurrency: Infinity,
    })
}
```

I am able to write normal tests but cant use ES6 Syntax here. When I try to import some react components I get this error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at http://localhost:9876/base/test/components.spec.js?b89d2ba6de494310860a60ad2e9e25aea5eb3657:2
```

So I have to setup babel somehow to compile my test files first. When I try to use `compilers: ['js:babel-core/register']` in my karma config its not gonna work.

I also have seen that `compilers` seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation) soon so I also tried `require: ['babel-core/register']` but it still won´t compile to use ES6 for my test files.

Any idea how to configurate my karma file to write my tests with ES6 ?

Just in case its important. This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin =  require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin({
            entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/sw.js'),
        }),
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: false,
        inline: false,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }

};
```

Comment: please also do `npm install karma-webpack` and add `webpack: require('./path-to-webpack-test-config')` to `'karma.config.js`. Part of webpack config regarding module should probably look like `module: {rules: [ {test: /tests.*\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, use: {loader: 'babel-loader', options: {presets: ['babel-preset-env']}}}]}`

Comment: you might also consider making several webpack configs for testing, development and production builds.

Comment: and I also forgot about adding `preprocessors: {'your-test-files-pattern': ['webpack']}` to `karma.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

To make things more clear here is a sample project (it's fully runnable, you can fill out files and play around). Just two things to mention: I used `jamsine` instead of `mocha` and real 'Chrome' browser instead of headless. Runnable via `npm run test` command.

files structure

```
/
    karma.conf.js
    package.json
    sample.js
    sampleTest.js
    webpack.test.config.js
```

`karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: ['*Test.js'],
    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],
    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    preprocessors: {
        '*Test.js': [ 'webpack'] //preprocess with webpack
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    reporters: ['progress'],
    // setting up webpack configuration
    webpack: require('./webpack.test.config'),
    // web server port
    port: 9876,
    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,
    // Concurrency level how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

`package.json` (only relevant stuff):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
        "karma": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-webpack": "^2.0.9",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    }
}
```

`sample.js`:

```
export default function(data){
        return data;
}
```

`sampleTest.js`:

```
import sample from 'sample';

describe('Sample', function(){

    it('is defined', function(){
        expect(sample).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('returns argument', function(){
        expect(sample(0)).toBe(0);
    })
});
```

webpack.test.config.js:

```
module.exports = { 
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /tests\/.*\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['babel-preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ["node_modules", './'],
        extensions: [".js"]
    }
};
```

Karma's webpack plugin is used to inform karma that it should prepare files using webpack and specific webpack configuration before sending them to the browser.

Please note key points:

- test files pattern in karma.conf.js
- pattern to preprocess files (should match the pattern above)
- webpack entry in karma.conf.js file
- module entry in webpack.test.config.js

p.s. personally I don't use separate patterns for files, I use a separate file (named, say, `tests.webpack.js`) to have a single place where the way to find test files is defined:

```
//make sure you have your directory and regex test set correctly
var context = require.context('.', true, /.*Test\.js$/i); 
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

and have in `karma.conf.js` (paths are irrelevant to sample project above):

```
files: [
    'tests/tests.webpack.js',
],
preprocessors: {
    './tests/tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack'] //preprocess with webpack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert ESModule in commonjs module with the [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) plugin

In your `.babelrc` file :

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

**Update :**
You can set the plugin in your webpack configuration :

```
{
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs')]
     }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your solution, but its not working. Still ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import```

Comment: Try to set the plugin in your webpack configuration: see my edit